# Can't get apache to load PHP as a module

Tags: php, apache

So I've looked all around google and have not been able to find a solution to this. I've tried everything I can think of and nothing seems to work. 
I'm running apache 2.2 and php 5.6.3.

First, I downloaded PHP manually and then changed the php-development file to my .ini file and uncommented the extension for windows. (I'm on a windows 7 machine)
Next I added an environment variable for PHP. After that I went into my apache config file and told it to load the module (which I had to download manually) And now everytime I try to start apache with the load module in the config file, apache gives me the operation could not be completed error.

I'm honestly completely new to php and apache, but from what I understand it should work from what I've done so far. does anyone know of something else I should/could do?

Here are the lines where I load the module in the config file

```
LoadModule php5_module "c:/php/php5apache2_2.dll"
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
PHPIniDir "c:/php"
```

Comment: Did you look at the apache error log file?

Comment: yup. Basically says the problem I know I'm having. Apache can't find my php module .dll even though I gave it the correct path.

Comment: If you're just trying to get started with PHP and Apache, I encourage you to get a distribution that has both of them pre-configured, instead of trying to get everything set up from scratch yourself. One good one is XAMPP, check it out. Super easy to get going.

Comment: first thing, it is to test your php installation. open a command shell and type 'php -v'. if it is returning informations about your php version, so we can go to the next step

Answer (score 0):

Mate, can you try like that and tell me if it is working for you:

```
LoadModule php5_module "c:\php\php5apache2_2.dll"
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
PHPIniDir "c:\php"
```

Comment: the '/' character is perfectly acceptable in filepaths on 'windows'.